# how to sort in array index to index

Tags: python, sorting

Hey everyone how can I sort array index to index. 
So I have code here

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

how can i sort to?

```
[0, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]
```

[this is my idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFynT.png)

Comment: Please explain your output more.

Comment: ok. sample in **a[0],a[1]** output is **a[0] = 0** a[1]=1 but move to a[2]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it sounds like you would like to return a list that is sorted like this:

```
[first_item, last_item, second_item, second_to_last_item, third_item, third_to_last_item,...]
```

I don't know of a one-line way to do that, but here's one way you could do it:

```
import numpy as np

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 7] # length of list is an odd number

# create indexes that are all positive
index_values = np.repeat(np.arange(0, len(a)//2 + 1), 2) # [0,0,1,1,.....]

# make every other one negative
index_values[::2] *= -1 #[-0, 0, -1, 1, ....]

# return a[i]
[a[i] for i in index_values[1:(len(a)+1)]]

### Output: [0, 7, 1, 3, 2]
```

It also works for lists with even length:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5] # list length is an even number
index_values = np.repeat(np.arange(0, len(a)//2 + 1), 2) # [0,0,1,1,.....]
index_values[::2] *= -1 #[-0, 0, -1, 1, ....]
[a[i] for i in index_values[1:(len(a)+1)]]

### Output: [0, 5, 1, 7, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an almost one liner (based on @Callin’s sort method) for those that want one and that can’t/don’t want to use pandas:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def custom_sort(a):
    half = len(a)//2
    return [n for fl in zip_longest(a[:half], a[:half-1:-1]) for n in fl if n is not None])
```

Examples:

```
custom_sort([0, 1, 2, 3, 7])
#[0, 7, 1, 3, 2]
custom_sort([0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5])
#[0, 5, 1, 7, 2, 3]
```

This can be done in one line, although you’d be repeating the math to find the halfway point

```
[n for x in zip_longest(a[:len(a)//2], a[:(len(a)//2)-1:-1]) for n in x if n is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we want to sort in place, that is without creating a new list. Here is what I came up with

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
for i in range(1, len(l), 2):
    l.insert(i, l.pop())
```